# Probelm with Add Network Analyst dll in My Web Mapping Application adf?

Tags: visual-studio, arcgis-web-adf

I'm a beginner in ArcGIS & I'm shooting blind really. I want to add the Network Analyst tool box to find the shortest path in my project. I tried this solution:

I can't add Network Analyst dll to my web mapping application. I use ArcGIS 10 & Visual Studio 10 and I used web application adf to build my website. I tried the Network Analyst toolbox or networkanalyst.dll from developer kit folder but an error occurs:

`there are no components in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.0\DotNet\ESRI.ArcGIS.NetworkAnalyst.dll that can be placed on toolbox`

Comment: I see you have multiple accounts on this site - [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15068/zaki-alshami) and [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15191/zaki-alshami).  Please consider merging them. http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Answer (score 1):

The WebADF is officially deprecated by Esri -- it's not recommended to start new development with that framework. The silverlight, flex and javascript wep APIs should be used going forward. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/

If you're comfortable with Visual Studio, you may want to use the Silverlight Viewer for ArcGIS for web mapping. It builds a nice web interface for web mapping similar to what the ADFs site builder does.

To use the Network Analyst Tools, you may be able to just add it from the builder to the generated site. If not, you can publish the Network Analyst tools as geoprocessing service and  then add it to your generated site. More information here http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-viewer/concepts/#/Add_geoprocessing_tasks/017700000051000000/

Comment: awesomo
thx 4 ur help
but i have to deliver my senior project after 6 days !!!!
if u can help how i can add network analyst
or provide with some codes to apply it in my project
any help well be appreciate